# Why does my data appear in the console 4 times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to get data from a weather api using React hooks. When I `console.log` the data after the useEffect hook it is printed to the console 4 times, twice as an empty object. Why is that? Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


export default function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState({})


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/hourly?city=Chicago,IL&key=XXX&hours=24')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => setData(response.data))
  }, []);

  console.log(data)
  
  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

and this is what is printed in the console:

> {}
>
> {}
>
> (24) [{},{}...]
>
> (24) [{},{}...]

Comment: Did you create the app with create-react-app? Is the entry element wrapped in `StrictMode`? If so, there are extra executions on development mode to detect potential issues, only in development mode: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One render happens with an empty object because the component mounts. Another happens with data because you set state. And then these are both doubled due to [Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)